# Which release of the spring portlet mvc framework is included in Liferay 6.0.6?

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, portlet

I noticed that there are already spring-*.jars in the ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/ directory of liferay tomcat. This is the Liferay core.

Which release of the spring mvc framework is included in Liferay 6.0.6?

Is there a newer spring release in Liferay 6.1?

Can import the classes in these spring jars into my own portlets? Or is this bad practice, or technically not advisable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liferay's sourcecode has a lib/versions.* file, there you should find everything you need to know about the versions of third party code in there. E.g. spring-*.jar in Liferay 6.1.0 is declared as being version 3.0.6. Check for the others.

Typically your plugins are free to use whatever library (and version) they want. It makes sense to standardize on the javascript side to introduce as few as possible libraries and versions to be embedded. On the server side you're free to use whatever you want.

If you want to use Liferay's versions, you can just declare what you'd like to use from Liferay (in WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties) - this will make a copy of Liferay's versions of those libraries available to your plugin.

Comment: Ah, so for liferay 6.0.6 this would be http://svn.liferay.com/repos/public/portal/tags/6.0.6/lib/versions.html, username guest, empty password. There it says it's 3.0.5 for liferay 6.0.6 (and 3.0.3 for liferay 6.0.5)